# object XMLParser is not a member of package com.DC.FTDataParser

Tags: scala

I am getting an error when i am trying to import a class

```
import com.DC.FTDataParser.XMLParser


  val nodes = getXML
```

object XMLParser is not a member of package com.DC.FTDataParser

Multiple markers at this line
- not found: value XMLParser
- not found: value XMLParser

Please find the class XMLParser. It is simple one to load XML from Yahoo

```
package com.DC.FTDataParser


class XMLParser //(fromccy: String, toccy: String) 
{
  import scala.xml._
  import java.net._
  import scala.io.Source

  def getXML = {

    XML.loadString(Source.fromURL(new URL("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDAUD%22,%22USDEUR%22,%22USDCAD%22,%22USDDKK%22,%22USDHKD%22,%22USDINR%22,%22USDJPY%22,%22USDKRW%22,%22USDBRL%22,%22USDMXN%22,%22USDCLP%22,%22USDPEN%22,%22USDCOP%22,%22USDNZD%22,%22USDNOK%22,%22USDSGD%22,%22USDSEK%22,%22USDCHF%22,%22USDGBP%22,%22USDUSD%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys")).mkString)     

  }



/*
  val exchange = nodes.foreach{ n => 
    val Name = (n \\ "Name").text.takeRight(3)
    val Rate = (n \\ "Rate").text
    val date = (n \\ "Date").text
    val Time = (n \\ "Time").text
    val Ask  = (n \\ "Ask").text
    val Bid  = (n \\ "Bid").text
    //println(s"$Name, $Rate,  $date")
  }*/


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two things:

1. `XMLParser` is a class. You need to have an instance of the class to call the `getXML` method. However, looking at your code, it may be enough to change it from being a `class` to being an `object`, then you will be able to call its methods.
2. `getXML` will be visible if you `import com.DC.FTDataParser.XMLParser._`

However, if you want to keep it as a class, then you can do

```
val parser = new XMLParser
val nodes = parser.getXML
```